# Can Orisa's 'Halt State' be unlocked with environmental kills?

Tags: achievements, overwatch

The description for Overwatch's '*Halt State*' achievement is "***Pull enemies into 1000 damage with a single use of Orisa's Halt! in Quick or Competitive Play***"

Do environmental kills count towards this achievement? For example, if I pulled a 600 HP Roadhog and a 500 HP Winston off the cliff on [Ilios](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Ilios), would that count for the achievement?

[image: 'Halt State' description]

Comment: I don't think environmental kills deal damage. If it did, I would have gold damage as lucio every time I was on Ilios. _Bye Hog_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754045961), environmental kills **do not** count towards that achievement.

> Orisa's achievement "Halt State" (unlocks pixel spray) does not take environmental kills into consideration

[Another thread](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754967216) supports this:

> I don't believe environmental kills count, tried that a few times when she first launched got nothing.

[This PSA](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5x62f6/orisa_halt_ability_doesnt_count_as_a_kill_if_you/) also confirms this behavior with a gif.

Comment: Wait, how does that GIF confirm this? If anything, it leads me to believe the opposite - notice how Orisa gets kill credit in the top right corner, plus she also gets 12% ult charge upon the robot's death.

Comment: @MageXy I used the wrong gif, that's how, that is embarrassing. Hold on.

Comment: I wouldn't change it. I'm pretty sure the one you posted is more recent. According to the [patch notes from March 21, 2017](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753508356), "Training bots that are destroyed in the Practice Range are now displayed in the kill feed". These notes came out ~20 days after that Reddit thread.

Comment: @MageXy yeah the gif i posted is from a thread saying that those kills are now displayed, but it still doesn't seem like environmental kills will count towards that achievement. I'm having issues getting the original gif to upload, though.

Comment: It is certainly quite possible that environmental kills count towards elimination credit and ult charge but not towards the achievement. A little counterintuitive, perhaps, but definitely a possibility. Unfortunately, it's hard to test since you can't get achievements in custom games.

Answer (score 6):

It [does not](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754045961) appear that environmental damage counts for the Halt State achievement. This is also supported by this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/5x62f6/orisa_halt_ability_doesnt_count_as_a_kill_if_you/) thread.

However, it is still possible to get Halt State, though it is a difficult achievement to get. [This thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/182930-overwatch/75204418) outlines a number of ways to get the achievement, including:

- Teaming up with a Reaper and pulling the enemies into a Death Blossom
- Using Halt in the middle of a Gravitron Surge which has captured a few enemies
- Using a Hanzo ultimate on King's Row Attack (and using the Halt to line the enemies up)

Comment: Hanzo ult doesn't need to be on King's Row, anywhere that contains a tighter choke will do.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf That is true, I was just trying to summarize what was written in the link in case it ever goes dead

Comment: There are a few different ults you can pull them into to do that much damage.  For instance, D.Va's ult does 1000 damage just on its own.

Comment: @Powerlord - *At ground zero **Per character. Pulse bomb can also work if you get a few people.